# Getting images and text from webpage with javascript and yql

Tags: javascript, yql

trying to learn how to parse pages with yql execute.  I want to return the text and images separately.  I also want to change the width of all the images.  Tried to write javascript for this but it isn't working.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

> ```
>        <execute><![CDATA[
>     var q = y.query('select * from html where url=@url and xpath=@xpath',{url:url,xpath:xpath});
>             var myresults = q.results;
>             var images = myresults.getElementsByTagName('img');
>             images.setAttribute('width','150');
>             text = myresults.getElementById("p").textContent;
>             response.object = <text>{text}</text> <images>{images}</images>;
>         ]]>
>         </execute>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do something very similar to what you want by just using th *html* table that is built into YQL. Here an example where I am selecting img and p elements from this [article](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9209140/Sentiment_analysis_comes_of_age).

I use two different XPath expressions within one Xpath:

```
//div[@id='left_col']//img
//div[@id='left_col']//p
```

The full query:

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9209140/Sentiment_analysis_comes_of_age" AND xpath="//div[@id='left_col']//img|//div[@id='left_col']//p"
```

Try it out.